# How to pass a variable size array of pointers as an argument to a function

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a char* data that I casted in order to access it like this

```
arr[2][3]
```

I proceeded that way :

```
char (*arr)[size] = (char (*)[size])data;
```

My problem is how can I pass "arr" as an argument to a function ?

```
void func(??? arr)
{
   ...
}

void test(char *data, int size)
{
   char (*arr)[size] = (char (*)[size])data;
   func(arr);
}
```

I don't know the value of "size" at compile time.

Also, I know that I could just access my value like this : data[2 * size + 3] but I need to avoid multiplications for speed constraints.

Comment: Just `void func(char **arr)`

Comment: VLA such as `char (*arr)[size]` is not standard C++. Anyway, you cannot cast `data` into such type, in the same way you cannot cast `apple` into `orange`. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: *"but I need to avoid multiplications for speed constraint"* - what do you think the compiler's going to have to do with the indices in `arr[x][y]` if you do give it knowledge of the array dimensions?

Comment: @101010 It would be so easy ;) but it doesn't compile

Comment: @Nawaz Sorry, I didn't mention this is C++11

Comment: @Olivier: VLA is not allowed in ANY version of C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, I know that I could just access my value like this : data[2 * size + 3] but I need to avoid multiplications for speed constraints.

This cannot be avoided in the way you proposed. If you access data like `x[2][3]`, what do you expect the compiler to do? It will translate the indexing it into the equivalent of `2 * size + 3`. If this is too slow for your problem, you are out of luck and need to find another way to gain time. The proposed solution which you cannot make work is not a solution, so it's pointless to even try it.

Perhaps you can change your code to use a different access pattern, one without so many complicated jumps that require all those multiplications? Linear memory accesses tend to be the best sort, because they take advantage of memory hierarchy; maybe you can just take advantage of that? It's hard to say what you can change without even know what the code does, though.

Comment: I decompiled to compare, and yes you are right, the compiler does multiply. So I got back to the multiplication version, but it still is slower. Then I suppose the compiler optimizes something somewhere anyway. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

> I have a char* data that I casted in order to access it like this

And that's the source of your problems. It's a contiguous memory block. Write a view facade if you need a different interface, or...

> My problem is how can I pass "arr" as an argument to a function ?

The easiest way is to avoid using (terrible) low-level primitives left in the language for C compatibility.

If you don't know the size at compilation time, use an `std::vector`. If you do know, use `std::array`.

> but I need to avoid multiplications for speed constraints.

Unless you have benchmark data to back that up, I am dismissing that requirement as a premature optimization.

Comment: This is again speed constraints that makes me code like C. I'm not looking for the easiest way. I'm doing real time image processing and I need to access tens of millions data in a few milliseconds.
Using std:vector considerably slows down the program.
Avoiding the multiplications the way I exposed makes me save a lot of time on the whole process. I just need to split my program into different functions because this is unreadable.

Comment: *Using std:vector considerably slows down the program.* - **citation needed**. Benchmark results. Code that used `std::vector`. Everything.

Comment: @Olivier $10 says you forgot to call `reserve`.

Comment: @Olivier Sounds like you are misusing something. Is this a debug build? Are you passing the vector by value? Did you `reserve()`? You need to provide a decent explanation for why std::vector considerably slows down the program. Fact is, std::vector is quite good in the vast majority of scenarios, so if it considerably slows down the program, that means your program has some very unusual characteristics. Knowing those very unusual characteristics is important for anyone trying to help you find a solution that avoids the same "mistakes" that std::vector supposedly does to make the program slow.

Comment: My char* data is returned by an external library, so this type cannot be changed. The length of the array is 1280 x 1024 x 4 = 5MBytes. To use std::vector, I need to reallocate the same large amount of memory, which is too much time consuming (about 12ms on my device) whereas the cast is immediate.

Comment: @Olivier Are you 100% positive that a 5MB block allocation is taking 12 milliseconds? How did you create that vector? Did you allocate by frame? Can you move out of that memory? If not, you need a weakly referencing facade.

Comment: Thanks for the $10 ! I'll have an ice cream cheers ;) More seriously, this is not a problem of memory or anything, my code compiles and runs well, I'm just looking for a way to pass this kind of type as argument. I'm not looking for a quite good way, or an easy way, I'm looking for the less time consuming way (my processing method takes 25ms), and in my case, every millisecond is important.

Comment: @Olivier no, you're not looking for a way to pass this kind of type as argument. That's the solution you came up with, but haven't actually confirmed that it solves your problem. It's not your problem. It's your proposed solution. Your problem seems to be that you need to make some unspecified code run faster. Focus on that.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes I do, it's on a custom embedded system with pretty low resources. All my image processing program is thought so that I always use the same pointer in memory (which is my image) from beginning to end, to limit memory usage.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Actually, my program works, but because I can't pass this argument, all the code is in one function, which is ugly.